# Html table cell edit textbox doesn't focus on input blur event not working

Tags: jquery, html

I have a very simple table structure

```
<table width='50%' align='center' id='tabs'>
  <tr>
    <td>1.00</td>
    <td>5.23</td>
    <td>6.12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2.45</td>
    <td>2.45</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3.12</td>
    <td>2.98</td>
    <td>2.09</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and here is my code which allows only to enter numeric in textinput with  two places after dot i.e it allows only numbers like eg 2.12 and the problem is if i click on table cell a textbox appears in that cell and i can edit numbers but when i click on table cell it should focus on textbox and after editing numbers as and when i come out of editing that blur event should work.

```
$("table td").click( function(e){   
    if($(this).find('input').length){
         return ;   
    }        
    var input = $("<input type='text' size='5' />").val( $(this).text() );
    $(this).empty().append(input);
    $(this).find('input')
    .focus(function(e){
        if($(this).val()=='0.00' || $(this).val()=='0'){$(this).val('');}
    }).keydown(function(event){
         if ( event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 27 || event.keyCode == 190  || event.keyCode == 13 || 
              // Allow: Ctrl+A
             (event.keyCode == 65 && event.ctrlKey === true) || 
             // Allow: home, end, left, right
             (event.keyCode >= 35 && event.keyCode <= 39)) {
             // let it happen, don't do anything
             return;
        }
        else {
            // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
            if (event.shiftKey || (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105 )) {
                event.preventDefault(); 
            }   }
    }).blur( function( e ){
                if($(this).val()!=""){
                    if (!isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()))) {
                        var val1=parseFloat($(this).val()).toFixed(2);
                        $(this).val(val1);
                        $(this).parent('td').text( 
                              $(this).val()
                        );
                      }
                    }
                    else{
                            $(this).parent('td').text("0.00");
                    }
            });    
});

 $(function() {
        $('table tr td').hover(function() {
            $(this).css('background-color', '#FFFFB0');
        },
        function() {
            $(this).css('background-color', '#F4F4F4');
        });
    });
```

[**Please see JS FIDDLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/v7znh/19/)

Comment: The blur event seems to be fired just fine, I'm not sure I understand the problem.

Comment: when i click on the table cell focus should be in the textbox

Comment: i would like to allow only one . in the textbox

Comment: when i click on another table cell i need to ensure previous table cell textbox should go away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will make it focus when you click on a field:

```
var input = $("<input type='text' size='5' />").val( $(this).text() );
$(this).empty().append(input);
input.focus();
```

Here's your updated JsFiddle:

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/v7znh/20/)

Comment: thnx this is working like a charm now i need to allow only one decimal point . in the table cell textbox i should restrict . if it exists previously

Comment: @Peter Rasmussen you saved my day.